# add subtitles in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

i want to add subtitles to a video. eg:- a video will be playing and user will select a point on video, he will add a subtitle and save it. Now when the user again plays the video the subtitles at those points are displayed

Comment: Try this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anilkumargupta/archive/2009/05/01/playing-subtitles-with-videos-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This article goes step-by-step on how to do this.

[1]: http://ashishware.com/SilverlightSub.shtml Add Subtitles to Silverlight Video